# Nomenclature Having Two or More descriptions and Units for a symbol

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I am using the following nomenclature setup

[image]

With the following code

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
  per-mode=symbol
  }

\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
    \item[\textbf{\textcolor{tudelft-cyan}{Acronyms}}]}{%                A - Acronyms
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
    \item[\textbf{\textcolor{tudelft-cyan}{Roman Symbols}}]}{%           R - Roman
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
    \item[\textbf{\textcolor{tudelft-cyan}{Greek Symbols}}]}{%           G - Greek
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
    \item[\textbf{\textcolor{tudelft-cyan}{Superscripts}}]}{%            S - Superscripts
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{U}}{%
    \item[\textbf{\textcolor{tudelft-cyan}{Subscripts}}]}{%              U - Subscripts
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
    \item[\textbf{\textcolor{tudelft-cyan}{Other Symbols}}]}{%           X - Other Symbols
  {}}}}}}}}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}%
  }

\makenomenclature
```

Which then generates the nomenclature using the following example

```
\nomenclature[a]{TPS}{Thermal protection System}%


\nomenclature[r]{$v$}{Fluid velocity\nomunit{\si{\metre\per\second}}}



\nomenclature[g]{$\tau$}{Longitude. Dimensional time \nomunit{\si{\radian}}}%
\nomenclature[g]{$\delta$}{Geocentric Latitude. Differential Operator. Radius of Trust Region \nomunit{\si{\radian}}}%
\nomenclature[g]{$\delta^*$}{Geodetic Latitude.  \nomunit{\si{\radian}}}%
```

**My Question is,**

How could I have two or more descriptions/units for the same symbol. As you can see i have to use the same symbols for different purposes.

Ideally I would like to have another line bellow Heading angle, with search direction with units [-] and two other lines bellow geocentric latitude with units [-] and m.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many entries as you want with the same symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{tudelft-cyan}{RGB}{0,166,214}

\sisetup{
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
  per-mode=symbol
}

\makenomenclature

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand\nomgroup{m}
 {
  \item[\textbf{\textcolor{tudelft-cyan}{\choosenomgroup{#1}}}]
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\choosenomgroup}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {A}{Acronyms}
    {R}{Roman~Symbols}
    {G}{Greek~Symbols}
    {S}{Superscripts}
    {U}{Subscripts}
    {X}{Other~Symbols}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Xyz

\nomenclature[a]{TPS}{Thermal protection System}

\nomenclature[r]{$v$}{Fluid velocity\nomunit{\si{\metre\per\second}}}

\nomenclature[g]{$\tau$}{Longitude \nomunit{\si{\radian}}}

\nomenclature[g]{$\tau$}{Dimensional time \nomunit{\si{\second}}}

\nomenclature[g]{$\delta$}{Geocentric Latitude \nomunit{\si{\radian}}}

\nomenclature[g]{$\delta$}{Differential Operator}

\nomenclature[g]{$\delta$}{Radius of Trust Region \nomunit{\si{\meter}}}

\nomenclature[g]{$\delta^*$}{Geodetic Latitude.  \nomunit{\si{\radian}}}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

I have streamlined the `\nomgroup` command, but your definition works as well.

[image]